# Multiple events on same element, stop immediate propagation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two click events on the same element. One of them is a delegated event, and the the other one is not.

```
$( document ).on( 'click.bar', 'p', function( e ) {

    console.log( 'click.bar', e );

    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

});

$( 'p' ).on( 'click.foo', function( e ) {

    console.log( 'click.foo' );

});
```

I want to disable the "click.foo" in a specific situation, when "click.bar" is executed. The problem is, that "click.foo" is always called before "click.bar" is called. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/
It will stop propagation above in DOM tree.

Comment: Unfortunately the stopPropagation function has no effect on delegated events.

Comment: You would need to use event capturing instead of event bubbling – http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing jQuery only supports bubbling event model.

Answer (score 0):

If you handle both events from `$(document)`, the `event.stopImediatePropagation` works fine.

You have to register the first event (the one with the `event.stopImediatePropagation`) first in the script, so it is called first when `document` is clicked.

```
$( document ).on( 'click.bar', 'p', function( e ) {

    console.log( 'click.bar', e );

    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

});

$( document ).on( 'click.foo', 'p', function( e ) {

    console.log( 'click.foo' );

});
```

Other way it won't work because jQuery bubbles the event up (inner to outer), so the event registered in `p` is triggered first before it reaches the `document`.